# add index Ruby on Rails 4.1.4 migration

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm creating a project in RoR and get a error when run "rake db:migrate":

```
Mysql2::Error: Key column 'item_id' doesn't exist in table
```

And I don't understand what I'm doing wrong:

This is my items migration

```
class CreateMerchants < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
       create_table :merchants do |t|
           t.string     :name,      null: false, limit: 100
           t.string     :address,   null: false, limit: 200

           t.timestamps
       end
   end
 end
```

And my purchases migration:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :purchases do |t|
        t.references    :purchasers,        null: false
        t.references    :items,             null: false
        t.references    :merchants,         null: false
        t.decimal       :purchase_count,    null: false, precision: 17, scale: 2

        t.timestamps
    end

    add_index       :purchases,     :item_id
    add_index       :purchases,     :merchant_id
    add_index       :purchases,     :purchaser_id
  end
end
```

Somebody can show me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that references expects a singular name, also you can create the index in the same line that create the reference so you migration should looks like:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :purchases do |t|
        t.references    :purchaser,        null: false, index: true
        t.references    :item,             null: false, index: true
        t.references    :merchant,         null: false, index: true
        t.decimal       :purchase_count,   null: false, precision: 17, scale: 2

        t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's worked but just for educational purposes, how should be my add_index in this case? Also it's more appropriate create in the same line or with the add_index?

Comment: Just like you are adding in your question: `add_index :purchases, item_id` the issue was that for examplo for item, using `t.references :items` it generates a field called `items_id` and not `item_id`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class CreatePurchases < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :purchases do |t|
        t.integer    :purchaser_id,        null: false
        t.integer    :item_id,             null: false
        t.integer    :merchant_id,         null: false
        t.decimal    :purchase_count,      null: false, precision: 17, scale: 2

        t.timestamps
    end

    add_index       :purchases,     :item_id
    add_index       :purchases,     :merchant_id
    add_index       :purchases,     :purchaser_id
  end
end
```